# How to name a lot of point of a KML file?

Tags: kml, csv, google-earth, kmz

I have a KML file with 5400 points with no name. I would like to name each point. My idea was to convert this KML file to CSV to rename quickly them and to convert back this CSV to KML, but I don't succeed doing it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of your file. I think I might be able to help you

Comment: In google earth ?

Comment: Like a code, if you can. Have you exported the.csv at all? If so, send me the screenshot or attach it to your query. Alternatively go with Google Earth if you can, whatever best for you for the time being.

Comment: It also depends on how would you name the point? Are you going to set one name for all the points or each point will have a different name?

Comment: I want to name them from 1 to 5400

Comment: I just converted my kml file to csv

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution: I imported my KML file to Excel opening it as a XML Table type file (the import made Excel load for a long time, but didn't crash). Then I could extract latitude and longitude data. I put them in a blank KML file that I created with Google Earth so this file was correctly formatted. Then I edited the "description" fields for each point, pulling my cells on Excel. Saving it in CSV, I can open it on Google Earth and save it in KML if I want.

Answer (score 0):

Without any screenshot is hard to help you, but if you have i.e. Notepad ++ you can try to Replace all blank names with the name you want.

I guess, your .XML code looks now as:

```
         <Placemark>
        <name></name>
```

Then after Crtl+F click toggle Replace and replace it with name you want, like below:

Thereafter each point will have a name.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, because I would have to name each point one by one

Comment: If you want to provide a unique name for every single point, you must fetch this data from somewhere if you wish to do it quickly. Have you got the file source?

Comment: Yes but I can't upload it, these are confidential datas.

Comment: Wha is the format of this data? Or file extension?

Comment: it is a kml file. (converted online to csv for the second picture)

Comment: So in this event, it looks like you haven't had the names from the very beginning. In this case, you have to do them manually if you want a different name for every point.

Comment: If it is possible to convert kml to csv easily, the inverse should be possible.

Comment: Try here: https://www.convertcsv.com/kml-to-csv.htm
or upload your kml file to QGIS and export it as the .csv